# Answer deleted by moderator, after upvotes and an awarded bounty

Tags: discussion, bounty, deleted-answers, vote-to-delete

This answer looks completely valid, has received 5 upvotes (plus one down) and a 250 bounty, but it was deleted by a moderator.  Now it cannot be undeleted by mere users.

Why was this done?  There is not a comment on the answer to indicate that there is any sort of problem.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60716157/1290634

Comment: What's really weird is that the same answer was reposted by the same user years after this meta post.

Answer (score 14):

Some answers are deleted because of reasons that are personal to that particular poster, and moderators opt to choose not to reveal those in public. If that particular poster comes forward with a meta, or flags their post asking for a reason, we'll gladly share the reason with them.

For more public reasons, like duplicates or plagiarism, we usually do leave a comment.

For now, you can be sure that the answer wasn't deleted willy-nilly. I have cross checked and made sure that the answer deletion was appropriate in that case.

Comment: @DavidArenburg I don't see any way OP could have answered differently. I'm not sure if rubbing in the moderator's deletion with such question is appropriate. Flagging deleted answer with custom flag would be better if you were just concerned about good answer being deleted *by mistake*.

Comment: The question chosen as a duplicate of mine tells me a lot more than does this answer, but thanks.